# How do I blit an f string to a if statement in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, dice

I'm making my first ever project which is a dice game in pygame where you press the y key to roll a dice and you verse the computer and whoever gets the higher roll wins. I got the whole game itself set up but I am having a very difficult time when it comes to displaying the text toward who won such as...
You won! opponent rolled a 3. I am able to show the text in the console itself, but not in the pygame window and don't know how to blit it in.

Reference Code...

```
import pygame
import random
import os
import os.path

WIDTH = 750
HEIGHT = 750
FPS = 60
QUARTER_WIDTH = WIDTH // 4
MIDDLE_HEIGHT = HEIGHT // 2
white = (255, 255, 255)



pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dice Game")

# Fonts and Text
title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 70)
title_label = title_font.render("Would You like to roll? Y/N", 1, (255, 255, 255))


# Load images
dice1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_1.png"))
dice2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_2.png"))
dice3 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_3.png"))
dice4 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_4.png"))
dice5 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_5.png"))
dice6 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_6.png"))

# Indexed list to reference all the faces
all_dice = [None, dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]
pygame.display.set_icon(dice6)

# Game Background
background = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "dice_board.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))


### Function to perform the random parts of the game
def rollDice():
    """ Generate the two random numbers, one for the Player and Opponent """
    player_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    opponent_roll = random.randint(1, 6)

    return player_roll, opponent_roll


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
player_face = None  # No dice before first roll
player_roll = 0
opponent_face = None  # No dice before first roll
player_roll = 0

while running:

    # handle user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_y:
                player_roll, opponent_roll = rollDice()
                player_face = all_dice[player_roll]
                opponent_face = all_dice[opponent_roll]

                # Debug prints
                font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
                text1 = font.render(f'opponent won. They rolled a {opponent_roll}', 1, white)
                text2 = font.render(f'You win! They rolled a {opponent_roll}', 1, white)
                text3 = font.render('Tied!', 1, white)
                textRect1 = text1.get_rect()
                textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
                textRect3 = text3.get_rect()
                textRect1.center = (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)
                textRect2.center = (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)
                textRect3.center = (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)
                if opponent_roll > player_roll:
                    print(f"opponent won. They rolled a {opponent_roll}")
                    window.blit(text1, textRect1)
                elif opponent_roll < player_roll:
                    print(f"You win! They rolled a {opponent_roll}")
                    window.blit(text2, textRect2)
                elif opponent_roll == player_roll:
                    print("tied!")
                    window.blit(text3, textRect3)

    # Reapint the screen
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    window.blit(title_label, (WIDTH // 2 - title_label.get_width() // 2, 250))

    # Paint the dice faces
    if (player_face != None):
        window.blit(player_face, (QUARTER_WIDTH, MIDDLE_HEIGHT))
    if (opponent_face != None):
        window.blit(opponent_face, (3 * QUARTER_WIDTH, MIDDLE_HEIGHT))

    # flush display changes
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Constrain FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: After you paint the text you overwrtite everything with `window.blit(background, (0, 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

To render tetx, you need to use pygame.font.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

basically, you'll have to create a bitmap font, use the font to render the text to a surface, and then blit the surface.

```
pygame.font.init() 
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 8)
helloWorld = myfont.render('Hello World', False, (0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(helloWorld,(20,30))
```